# Saying korbonos

Tags: halacha, minhag, tzibur-community, korbanos-ketores-prayers

Do you have to say korbonos? If so, why is it not said with the shaliach tzibbur?

Comment: Yankel, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: See this related answer to a different question: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1810/repeating-seder-hakitores/1813#1813 In it, Shalom mentions that the purpose of saying this paragraph is to fill in for the _karbanos_ we are failing to bring.

Answer (score 7):

Have to? I would think not. To cite the [Tur, siman 1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90):
וטוב לומר פרשת העקידה, ופרשת המן, ועשרת הדברות, ופרשת הקרבנות, כגון פרשת העולה ומנחה ושלמים וחטאת ואשם. אמנם פרשת הקרבנות טוב יותר לאומרה ביום, שהם במקום הקרבת הקרבן שזמנו ביום. וכשיסיים פרשת העולה, יאמר: רבון העולמים! יהי רצון מלפניך שיהא זה חשוב ומקובל לפניך כאילו הקרבתי עולה בזמנה. וכן יאמר בפרשת המנחה והשלמים והאשם. ואחר פרשת החטאת לא יאמר כן, לפי שאינה באה נדבה.

It is rather clear that he considers it "tov", or "tov yoteir", to say them, rather than obligatory.

Looking then to Shulchan Aruch, [same siman](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90), seif 5:
טוב לומר פרשת העקדה, ופרשת המן, ועשרת הדברות, ופרשיות עולה ומנחה ושלמים וחטאת ואשם. הגה: ודוקא ביחיד מותר לומר עשרת הדיברות בכל יום, אבל אסור לאומרם בצבור (תשובת הרשב"א סימן קמ"ד) .

Thus, the mechaber (Rav Yosef Karo) encodes it just like the Tur, as "tov lomar". And the Rema adds a gloss on the aseres hadibros, but does not disagree. He agrees it is not obligatory.

Of course, since it is common to say it, they will discuss aspects of how to say it. But that does not mean that it is obligatory, contrary to the other answer given here.

Now, should you say it? Ask your local Orthodox rabbi. I'd refer you to the Tur, and actually to the Mechaber in the previous seif:
טוב מעט תחנונים בכוונה, מהרבות בלא כוונה.

So this might be an assessment. If you can have better kavvana by davening slowly and so being able to focus on your words, then it might be better to do this than to daven up the korbanos and then psukei dezimra. Of course, if you have the time and the patience, say everything slowly and with kavana. But I thinks that this is a subjective assessment.

That said, it is certainly GOOD to say the korbanos, all else being equal.

Comment: "Good" answer .

Comment: _Tov m'at b'chavana_ is inherently assuming a less-than-ideal state. I assume the questioner was asking about a _l'chatchila_ state.

Comment: josh, note the difference in the language of the Tur and Mechaber. It could be the Mechaber holds the Tamid is more than "Tov Lomar".

Comment: certainly possible; and you could say the same based on the same siman (45).

Comment: do you mean the difference in the word כגון?

Answer (score 6):

As to whether one must say *korbanos*, see your local *sidur*. Obviously, you have to: it's part of the service.

What, you didn't like that proof?

Fine.

Here's the *Rama* ([48](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%97)) on the subject:

> Then we say the paragraph of the *tamid* and some say the order of the pyre and "*ribon haolamim ata tzivisanu*...", and if you can't say it with the *tzibur* you can say it at home and review the paragraph of the *tamid* alone with the *tzibur* and have in mind the second time as one reading the Torah.

The *Shulchan Aruch* (there) says:

> On *Shabas* we say near the paragraph of the *tamid* the verses of the *musaf* of *Shabas*, but not on *rosh chodesh* or *yom tov*...

and the *Rama* adds:

> but some say we mention the *musaf* of *rosh chodesh* too, and that's how we act....

The *Mishna B'rura* there (:1) says

> ...we say every day the topics of the making of the *k'tores*...

— referring to the *tora sheb'al pe*.

Then in [50](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0), the *Shulchan Aruch* says:

> They established to review, after the paragraph of the *tamid*, the chapter "*Ezehu M'koman*" and the *baraysa* of *R' Yishmael*...

I'm just quoting stuff, I hope (don't count on it) correctly; [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for a practical ruling.

**Update, later:** Nothing I wrote here is incorrect AFAICT, but see the other posted answer for perhaps a better take on the issue.