# Why do nusach Ashkenaz shuls outside of Israel skip reciting the korbanot section of davening?

Tags: tefilla, korbanos-ketores-prayers

According to [this article](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Korbanot#Parts_of_Korbanot) reciting *parashat hatamid* is considered a *chiuv deoraita* (biblical obligation) at least by Rabbeinu Yonah ( more than can be said about most other parts of *davening*). Yet in my experience, most *nusach Ashkenaz* synagogues outside of Israel completely skip that section. They begin with *birkot hashachar*, continue with *le'olam yhei adam* and *shma'*, and then after the *berakha* of *mikadeish et shimcha barabim* they skip a bunch of pages straight to *Rabbi Yishmael omer*.

What is the reason that many *shuls* skip over this section and how do they justify skipping a section that (at least according to one opinion) is more important than most of the other parts of *davening* that they actually *do* say?

The reason I am focusing on *nusach Ashkenaz* synagogues outside of Israel is because in my experience Sephardi synagogues do say the *korbanot* and in Israel most Ashkenazi synagogues start with *Rabbi Yishmael omer* (presumably people say *korbanot* before getting to shul). My question is not meant to be limited to Ashkenaz shuls in chu"l.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't saying just the Tamid before RY? That's what I do when I'm Chazzan in a place that "doesn't say korbanot"

Comment: @DoubleAA I am sure that at least some don't say the _tamid_. They say the _berakha_ and then say _Rabbi Yishmael_ out loud immediately. Maybe that's the wrong thing to do, but I believe it's widely done.

Comment: Reason that I've commonly heard - "It takes too much time; people have to get to work." (One or two had the "nerve" to call it "tircha detzibbur"!) I'm not saying this is a good reason. Sounds more like a poor excuse to me.

Comment: @DanF Those only apply to the "rest" of Korbanot. The Tamid is more important than most of Pesukei Dizimra for sure.

Comment: I noticed this when I went to the USA. In the UK we don't normally skip them and some say the incense passages too (we don't). But ArtScroll is an American siddur and contains all these sections so it is likely they are said at least in parts of the USA.

More korbanot is helpful for latecomers too.

Comment: I'm surprised people consider this a halakhik requirement. It's not something mentioned in Shas or Rambam, as far as I know. I thought it was just one possible topic for study to be 'over le-asiyah' after birkot ha-torah.

Comment: @paquda The Tur ([OC 48](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%97#fn_.28.D7.90.29)) sources the practice to a Midrash. In 47 he quotes his father (Rosh) that the Tamid should only be said during the daytime, so it seems he took it as more than a study suggestion. In any event, saying the Tamid is certainly a far older and established practice than much of Pesukei DiZimra or eg. LeDavid Hashem Ori. Whether it's technically "a halakhik requirement" is probably largely a semantic issue.

Comment: everything up until pesuke d'zimra is meant to be said by the individual at home. In some ashkenaz shuls morning brachos are repeated by the chazzan based on the understanding of how a person can be a tzadik each day. I don't recall how exactly it is broken up but it includes saying kadosh kadosh kadosh so many times, a day, hearing kaddish a certain amount of times each day, saying 100 brachas each day, and saying amen  a certain number of times each day. Repeating the brachas in shul helps people say amen more times

Comment: possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5412/759

Comment: The Gemara says in Berachot, Tefillah is one of the thing שעומדים ברומו של עולם, ובני אדם מזלזלין בהם. I hope this comment is a chizuk to all of us to daven properly.

Answer (score 6):

In one synagogue that "doesn't say *korbanos*", the rabbi explained to me that he recites the entire *korbanos* until "*Ezehu m'koman*" before arriving in the synagogue and the rest in the synagogue, and that he encourages everyone to do the same. [But I guess he only encourages it if someone brings it up, since I'd never heard him do so until I asked.] (He said the same about *mincha*'s *korbanos*.)

Comment: So what does the person who is leading the beginning part do? Or do people only say to themselves the parts that aren't said out loud in shul?

Comment: In that synagogue (as in most _Ashk'nazi_ ones in my experience), _korbanos_ aren't said aloud by the leader, @Daniel.

Comment: My question was about the other stuff that _is_ said aloud. Does the congregation say _birkos hashachar_ at home too, or just _korbanos_?

Comment: @Daniel, in that particular _shul_, no one says _b'rachos_ at the _amud_, either, but that's irrelevant, because [it's only one _shul_](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence). The relevance of what that _shul_ does is as an idea for what others **might** do, in which case they **can** say the _b'rachos_ aloud.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i believe to be the answer (i did not take a poll of actual shuls, as that would be the only real way to find out the answer to your question.):

The fact that you found an opinion that requires karbanos as being min hatorah, does not necessarily constitute halacha (or there is some other way of being yotzei his opinion...). that having been said, this opinion is not codified in shulchan aruch as an obligation, but rather as a good practice ("טוב לומר"). see [this hebrew article](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/2776#1b).

As such, it is not so hard to believe that shuls will leave this "good practice" to the discretion of each shul member, to decide if they have the time or patience to participate in this great practice.

Comment: If Shuls aren't requiring optional things then why do they say Shir Shel Yom? Clearly the Tamid is more important than that! Anim Zmirot is definitely no more than a good practice. Ledavid Hashem is barely 200 years old. Why do Shuls allow such things to be said on everyone's time??

Comment: @DoubleAA not all shuls say anim zemiros, and if they want to say it it has to be on everyone's time. all the rest are after aleinu, and if no one wants to say kaddish everyone can leave.

Comment: Of course some places don't say anim zmirot, but those that do should also say the Tamid if your reason for why some don't say it is correct

Comment: But tamid does not require opening the ark

Comment: Neither does anim zmirot and anyway why does opening the ark matter at all?

Comment: i have never seen anim zmirot without opening the ark, and the ark is opened only for tzibur needs, not any guy who is interested in doing so

Comment: I'm not aware of any rules about when the ark may, must or may not be opened, or any prayers which may must or may not be recited while the ark is specifically opened or specifically closed. It's all just local practice. Not that I see how any of this relates to my point above about the Tamid. Your claim that Shuls don't do things which are just good practice is wrong, as shown by my counterexamples above

Comment: you misunderstand, the idea is that this is something that many people skip because they don't have enough time or are late, so that may be how this developed, i did not mention any rule about shuls not engaging in good practices. it was just important that it is not strict halacha.

Comment: @heshy Shmoozing is not *halacha* either. Yet, many shuls find time to do that :-)

Comment: :O i'm horrified!!