# Why don't we say Korban HaTamid twice a day?

Tags: korban, korbanos-ketores-prayers

In Shacharit, we say Korban HaTamid in the Korbanot section, as a way for us to "bring" the Tamid offering which we no longer can bring without the Beit HaMikdash. However, the Tamid was brought twice a day during the days of the Beit HaMikdash. Therefore, it would make sense for us to say the Parsha twice, once for each time we bring the daily offering.

So, why is Tamid not a part of the Mincha service?

Should one say it twice a day, with the Yehi Ratzons?

Are there any sources that one *should* say this twice a day?

Comment: Who is we? It's in my siddur before mincha ;-) (although I don't say it)

Comment: I don't know why many people don't say it but the [Rema says to](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.234.1?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: I say it at Mincha. The Rama says to do so. I don't know what you mean by it's not in the service. Most people don't say at Shacharit either but that doesn't make it not part of the service

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe they mean it's not in the ArtScroll siddur? :-)

Comment: @DoubleAA I think what OP may mean is that (in many congregations) there is a chazzan who begins shacharit with birchot hashachar which is followed by korbanot, as opposed to mincha where the chazzan only begins at ashrei

Comment: @JoelK it's not that common to see a chazzan actually say the Tamid in the morning either. Most congregations skip right to R Yishmael.

Comment: @JoelK https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68388/759

Comment: @DoubleAA https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/why-do-nusach-ashkenaz-shuls-outside-of-israel-skip-reciting-the-korbanot-sectio#comment195299_68388 Maybe OP is British...

Comment: To clarify: I have used a plethora of Askenaz siddurim (artscroll, koren, otherwise) and they start Mincha at ashrei. nowhere does it say a reference to Tamid. However, every siddur has it in shacharit, and yes the chazzanim where I daven say korbanot semi-out loud.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a good halachic reason to say it at shacharis but not at mincha. The Rema (Orach Chayim 234:1) says that it's a good minhag:

> יש שכתבו שנהגו לומר פרשת קודם אשרי של תפילת המנחה נגד תמיד של בין הערביים ומנהג יפה הוא
>
> There are those who wrote that it was customary to say the parashat Hatamid before Ashrei of mincha, equivalent to the afternoon Korban Tamid, and this is a good minhag.

(The language of 'Minhag' is also used by the Shulchan Aruch when he says to say it at shacharis)

However, the mishna brura does say on this seif:

> ט"ז ומ"א כתבו לומר אחר אשרי אבל אין המנהג כן
> The Ta"z and Magen Avraham write to say it after Ashrei (of mincha), but this is not the minhag

Which seems to show that it wasn't a very widespread minhag, otherwise there would presumably be a consensus on when it should be said. (Though this is definitely debatable.)

However, a reason why saying Parashat Hatamid in the morning may be more popular, is that the shulchan aruch says to say it (for example O"Ch 1:9), and not 'just' the Rema. Another possible reason is what the Shulchan aruch says (50:1):

> קבעו לשנות אחרי פרשת התמיד פרק איזהו מקומן וברייתא דרבי ישמעאל כדי שיזכה כל אדם ללמוד בכל יום מקרא משנה וגמרא...
> They set the learning of chapter 'Eizehu Mekoman' and the Braisa of Rebbi Yishmael after Parashat Hatamid, so that one may merit learning Pessukim, Mishna and Gemara...

Since this reason, at least, is not applicable in the afternoon, it may be why people are less makpid.

Another possibility is that some shuls say the morning brachos as part of shacharis, maybe to make sure that everyone says the brachos, and once they're already saying brachos, they might as well say 'everything else' between them and the beginning of shacharis, whereas at mincha there is nothing to say beforehand that would lead to also saying Parashat Hatamid.